# calculate the total of a variable based on another variable in JS controller lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, list, map, array, js-controller

```
finalMap=[{"key":"OTC","subprocessName":"CXO","weightage":50},
{"key":"OTC","subprocessName":"Order Management","weightage":50},
{"key":"RTR","subprocessName":"Fixed Asset Accounting","weightage":20},
{"key":"RTR","subprocessName":"Intercompany Accounting","weightage":30},
{"key":"EPM","subprocessName":"Management Reporting","weightage":100},
{"key":"AP","subprocessName":"Travel & Expense","weightage":100}]
```

I would like to calculate the sum of weightages based on Key:

expected output:

```
{OTC :100,RTR:50,EPM:100,AP:100}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Loop Through the Array of JSON using `forEach()`
- I used [hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to check the property in Object
- Use the condition operator to check the key present in an object(output).

> Below is the code I changed, Please see [codepen](https://codepen.io/sarveshgithub/pen/xxKyBeq?editors=0111)

```
let finalMap=[{"key":"OTC","subprocessName":"CXO","weightage":50},
{"key":"OTC","subprocessName":"Order Management","weightage":50},
{"key":"RTR","subprocessName":"Fixed Asset Accounting","weightage":20},
{"key":"RTR","subprocessName":"Intercompany Accounting","weightage":30},
{"key":"EPM","subprocessName":"Management Reporting","weightage":100},
{"key":"AP","subprocessName":"Travel & Expense","weightage":100}]

let output = {}
finalMap.forEach(function(tax){
     output.hasOwnProperty(tax.key) ? output[tax.key] = output[tax.key] + tax.weightage : output[tax.key] = tax.weightage
})
```

Output

```
Object {
  AP: 100,
  EPM: 100,
  OTC: 100,
  RTR: 50
}
```

Comment: thanks Sarvesh. it worked

Comment: @VanajaKasaragadda Apologies for the prior comment. Here's an alternative: `let output = finalMap.reduce((p,v)=>{p[v.key]=(p[v.key]||0)+v.weightage;return p;},{});`